# Linearly Dependent Rows and Rank Graphical Understanding

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I was having trouble today understanding the correlation between linearly dependent rows and the rank of a matrix. Based on my teaching, we can determine rank by solving for reduced row-echoleon form and simply count all the non-zero rows. This means all the fully 0 rows were linearly dependent on another and cancelled out.

Now, this idea would make much more sense to me if it referred to the columns of the matrix because I always pictured linear transformations as the unit vectors moving to the column vectors' coordinates. If two columns were colinear their span would become a line and thus the matrix output would lose a dimension.

However, reduce row echoleon uses linearly dependent rows to determine rank instead of columns. This idea does not quite make sense to me and I was hoping someone could clarify it based on my understanding.

Thanks

Comment: Row rank equals column rank. Row rank is number of nonzero rows in reduced row-echelon form, column rank is number of columns with a leading 1 in reduced row echelon form, and these are two ways of describing the same number.

Comment: Did that comment help any?

Comment: Earth to Mathew, come in, please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.